# Mapping Email Claim when federating with another Azure AD B2C tenant

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I need to allow users to sign-up and sign-in in my application protected with Azure AD B2C with an Identity Provider that is another Azure AD B2C tenant. I have followed this official documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-b2c?pivots=b2c-user-flow

The thing is that when the user Authenticates in my application and try to sign-up with his Account from the other B2C Tenant, my application is always asking for the email attribute instead of getting it from the IDP, this is happening even if in the section "Identity provider claims mapping" y set `Email: email`.

Am I missing something here?

Here is the screen that shows up when user try to sign-up in my application using his other B2C Tenant Account. I don’t want users needs to write their email again, instead I want the email came from the IDP and map to my attributes automatically. I am using User Flow Policy.

[image]